# Python Remove separated commas from a two dimensional list

Tags: python, list

I have a two dimensional list and I cannot figure out how to remove the comma that separates the elements.

Code :

```
a1 = ["a1,", "a2b"]
a2 = ["a3,", "a4"]
a4 = []
a4.append(a1 + a2)
res = [[j.strip(',b') for j in i] for i in a4]
print(res)
```

Currently I can remove the `,`'s seperator in the lists but what I ideally want is the two dimensional list to be

`[['a1' 'a2' 'a3' 'a4']]` separated by spaces instead of commas

instead of

`[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']]`

I have also tried

```
c = []
for a in res:
    for b in a:
        b.strip(',')
        c.append(b)
print(c)
```

This does remove the `,` but the same problem persists as when the data is appended back into an list it's separated by `,`.

Comment: Sure it's possible, if you print it to look that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two kinds of commas here. You have the commas that are in the actual strings `"a1,"`. You can get rid of those with `strip(',')`. Then you have the commas that Python adds to the string representation of lists. To get rid of those, make your own string rather than relying on the Python default. Together that might look like:

```
a1 = ["a1,", "a2b"]
a2 = ["a3,", "a4"]
a4 = a1 + a2

res = " ".join(el.strip(',') for el in a4)
print(f"[[{res}]]")
# prints [[a1 a2b a3 a4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
You can enclose the stripped string into a `''` using `f-string`

```
a1 = ["a1,", "a2b"]
a2 = ["a3,", "a4"]
a3=' '.join(f"'{j.strip(',')}'" for j in a1+a2)
print(f"[[{a3}]]")
```

Output:

```
[['a1' 'a2b' 'a3' 'a4']]
```